# How to Parameterize jsonSurfer collectOne method - Java/Json Parsing

Tags: java, json

Let's say I have a file sample.json

```
{"Students":
[
{"Name": "ABC", "id" = "one"},
{"Name": "XYZ", "id" = "two"}
]
}
```

How do I retrieve an array element object by passing its index number as an argument ?

For example, I want to get array element with variable name ABC. So indexNum is 0 in this case.

I tried below but it doesn't work.

```
InputStreamReader reader = read("sample.json");
Object obj = jsonSurfer.collectOne(reader,"$.Students[indexNum]");
```

Not sure if JsonSurfer supports parametrizarion. Any suggestions please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
int indexNum = 0;
String jsonPath = "$.Students["+indexNum+"]";
Object obj = jsonSurfer.collectOne(reader,jsonPath);
```

Comment: Is there any way to collect object using id or name value instead of index number in jsonPath string. Ex: $.Students[id,'one']. I know that @ operator is not supported currently by json surfer. Reason using behind using json surfer is its streaming and easy xpath like access capability

Comment: You can collect all Student object and do the filtering yourself in the listener. Here is the sample for listene: https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer#surfing-in-json-dom-tree-collecting-matched-value-in-the-listeners

Comment: Thanks for directing me to it. Looks like it requires a complex code though to implement it.